# PostgreSQL Logon After Installation

Tags: postgresql, installation, credentials

I'm running PostgreSQL on CENTOS 7. I recently uninstalled an older version PostgreSQL 9.2. I then installed PostgreSQL 9.6. I was able to successfully run the `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb`

When I execute the command `su - postgres` I'm prompted for a password. I enter my sysadmin password but authentication fails. Therefore I'm unable to setup a new DB environment. I may have gotten my first install work, but I've forgotten the password. I thought by doing an uninstall of the older release using `yum remove postgresql` my new install would work just fine. How to I get pass this point? I can do another uninstall but I think the results will be the same.

- Is there a hidden file from my previous install that contains the old password?
- If so, how do I remove it to make my new install work?

Thanks

Comment: `sudo su - postgres`?

Comment: I discovered why I'm getting this error message the userid does not exist.  I'm new to PostgreSQL and Linux.  So please ignore this post